Add an array of data to an useState empty array using useState setter function in Reactjs
Hello I am working on a personal project and I can't seem to add an array of data that I am fetching from the backend to a useState array I can see the array but when I try to update it using the useState setter function it doesn't work or show no update at all.
I am feeling so dumb on this and have been stuck for around 3 hrs.
I am attaching my react code and a screenshot of the Google Chrome inspection tool. Please mention if you need more code I will try to provide as much as possible.
Thank you.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

const UseGetconversation = async () => {
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
  const [Conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getconversation = async () => {
      setloading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("api/users/");
        if (res.error) {
          throw new Error(res.error);
        }
        const data = res.data;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(Array.isArray(data));
        setConversations(data);
        console.log(Conversations);
      } catch (error) {
        toast.error(error.message);
      } finally {
        setloading(false);
      }
    };

    getconversation();
  }, []);

  return { loading, Conversations };
};

export default UseGetconversation;

enter image description here

I did read it after you have mentioned and now kinda feel more dumb for not coming across it. I did follow it but a small problem arised in which when I return the conversation value and access in another component I get undefined. Do you have any idea.

@GauravBisht: If you have some other code which produces some other problem, please ask a new question and include a [mcve] which demonstrates that problem, as well as any debugging information you have in your attempt to solve that problem.

okk @David I will try do so from next time. Thanks for guiding.

You are already using axios then use "axios().then" to set the value in state and "axios.catch()" to catch errors.

@DhruvilMehta actually I chain the axios request and resolve the promises in a single chain but for learning purposes I trying to break the chain and do it separately. (I don't if its called promise chain or not I just think of it like that my bad if I am wrong)

@DhruvilMehta: The code shown is already successfully using await.  Mixing await with .then() callbacks is a recipe for bugs.

@David I meant using ".then" instead of  async await and not using "aync-await" with "then"

@DhruvilMehta: Why?  What would that accomplish?  In what way do you think using async/await is somehow incorrect for awaiting Promises?  The problem in the code shown is addressed in the linked duplicate and has nothing to do with Promises.

 const data = res.data;
 console.log(data);
 console.log(Array.isArray(data));
 setConversations(data);
 console.log(Conversations);

Let's focus on the main part of the code, I am considering that your respective BE is returning an array as res.data nothing else like an object.
console.log(data);
console.log(Array.isArray(data));
I assume that these consoles return you with array data and true.
So when you try to set a array in state, directly dumping doesn't helps
Write it like this
setConversations([...data]);    >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Always use the spread operator to set state, it will work as expected.
And one more thing to add beyond your scope as a tip
console.log(Conversations);
You are trying to print the Conversations state just after setting it. state setting is async so that it will console an empty array. As Js will not wait until the state is set. It will execute the next line. If you want to console or see the data that is set use callbacks. This means console after data is set.

thanks I understand you solution yeah I was trying to access the data right after setting it but I thought maybe await is handling it but after reading the docs and understanding how async await works I seem to understand the underlying problem in the code and my approach. Now I am just feeling more dumb for sitting on this for 3 hrs. Thanks a lot again mate.

Welcome, and in fucntion based component useState does not provide direct way to pass callback which will execute after state update so we can do like this
setConversations([...data]);
then write useEffect
useEffect(()=>{console.log(Conversations)}, [Conversations])
and in class based u can pass callback
this.setState({Conversations: [data]}, ()=>{console.log(Conversations)})
If it helped please upvote to help others too.
